# Typecast one object based on same keys of another object

Tags: javascript

I have two objects with same properties. First object has properties with values(all string). And the second has the same properties but with different types (number, date).
What I'm trying to do is convert the first object properties to the types of second object for each property

First Object

```
{
   id:"2",
   id2:"12",
   id3:"someting"
}
```

Second Object

```
{
   id:1,
   id2:13,
   id3:"something else"
}
```

**Expected output of First Object is**

```
{
   id:2,
   id2:12,
   id3:"someting"
}
```

I have tried everything like `Object.assign()` and `Object.setPrototypeOf()`
and so on. Thanks you.

Comment: And I dont see any attempt. `Object.assign` is used to copy object not change value's type. Use `return Number(value).isInteger ? Number(value) : value`

Comment: `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)`

Comment: @dfsq. Doesnt work. it just copies data.

Comment: Object.assign should work as @dfsq has shown. If you're facing some issue, then share the code as well.

Comment: so you want all numbers to be typecasted to integer from string or if second obj has string then it should be string?

Comment: Yes . I want all numbers to be typecasted to integer from string @AZ_

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala Assign just copies data. i dont want to copy data. i just want to typecast it.

Comment: This can be done - write a method  taking a reference and a target and then make typecast accordingly for every key

Comment: @dfsq. can you please suggest edit??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create more generic approach to cast in any possible type and with ability to add new type if necessary:

```js
const obj1 = {
  id:"2",
  id2:"12",
  id3:"someting",
  test: 123,
  created: '2019/07/22',
}
const obj2 = {
  id:1,
  id2:13,
  id3:"something else",
  test: '123',
  created: new Date(),
}

const castMap = {
  Number: Number,
  String: String,
  Date: (value) => new Date(value),
}

Object.entries(obj1)
  .forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj2[key]).match(/\s(.+)]$/)[1]
    obj1[key] = castMap[type](value)
  })

console.log(obj1)
```

Comment: How about `obj2[key].constructor.name` instead of `toString.call()` (Assuming there are no null or undefined values)

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the value into the constructor of your generic object, consider the following:

```js
let obj1 = {
  id: "2",
  id2: "12",
  id3: "someting",
  d: "2019-07-22 09:15:29"
};

let obj2 = {
  id: 1,
  id2: 13,
  id3: "something else",
  d: new Date()
};

let res = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => (acc[key] = obj2[key].constructor(val), acc), {});

console.log(res);
```